# Почему не отображается css?

Tags: html, css, eclipse, tomcat

У меня в проекте 2  **html** файла, для каждого из них есть свой **css** файл.

**HTML 1:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <title>Company</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style/company.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
    <h1 align="center">Hello Company</h1><br/><br/>
        
        <div id="result_form">
            <form id="company" method="GET" action="CompanyServlet">
            
            <a href="./html/coupon_html_page.html" class="create_link">Create Company</a><br/><br/>
            
            <input type="button" value="Remove Company" class="btn" /><br/><br/>
            <input type="button" value="Update Company" class="btn" /><br/><br/>
            <input type="button" value="Get Coupon" class="btn" /><br/><br/>
            <input type="button" value="Get All Coupons" class="btn" /><br/><br/>
            <input type="button" value="Get Coupon By Type" class="btn" /><br/><br/>
            <input type="button" value="Get Coupon Till Price" class="btn" /><br/><br/>
            <input type="button" value="Get Coupon Till Date" class="btn" /><br/><br/>
            
            </form>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS 1:**

```
@CHARSET "windows-1255";


body {
        background-image: url('../img/backgroundLogin.gif');
        background-size: 100%;
    }
    
    h1{
        color: #191919;
        font-size: 300%;
        margin-top: 30px;
        text-shadow: 2px 2px white;
    }

    .create_link{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        font-size: 20pt;
        margin-left: 80px;
        text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
     }
```

**HTML 2:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <title>Coupon</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style/coupon.css" />
    </head>

    <body>          
        <h1>Coupon</h1>
        <div>
        <form action="CouponServlet" method="get">
            <input name="coupon_title" type="text" size="25" maxlength="30" value="" class="textField_title" placeholder="Title"/>
            <input name="coupon_message" type="text" size="25" maxlength="30" value="" class="textField_message" placeholder="Message"/>
            <input name="coupon_image" type="text" size="25" maxlength="30" value="" class="textField_image" placeholder="Image?"/><br/>
            
            <a class="text_Date">Start date</a>
            <input name="coupon_start_date" type="date" size="25" maxlength="30" value="" class="Date"/>
            
            <a class="text_Date">End date&nbsp;</a>
            <input name="coupon_edn_date" type="date" size="25" maxlength="30" value="" class="Date"/><br/>
            
            <input name="coupon_price" type="text" size="25" maxlength="30" value="" class="textField_price" placeholder="Price"/>
            <input name="coupon_amount" type="text" size="25" maxlength="30" value="" class="textField_amount" placeholder="Amount"/><br/>
            
            <p><select name="coupon_Type">
            <option>Select Coupon type</option>
            <option value="RESTAURANS">Restaurant</option>
            <option value="ELECTRICITY">Electricity</option>
            <option value="FOOD">Food</option>
            <option value="HEALTH">Health</option>
            <option value="SPORTS">Sports</option>
            <option value="CAMPING">Camping</option>
            <option value="TREVELLING">Trevelling</option>
            </select></p>
            
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button_sub" id="btn"/>
            <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="button_res" id="btn"/>
        </form>
        </div>
        

    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS 2:**

```
@CHARSET "windows-1255";

body {
    background-image: url('../img/backgroundLogin.gif');
    background-size: 100%;
    }
    
    h1{
        color: white;
        font-size: 45pt;
        margin-left: 80px;
        text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
     }
     
     div {
        margin-left: 260px;
        width: 700px;   height: 380px;
        background: #335CAD;
        border: 3px solid #fff;
        border-radius: 15px;
        }
        
        select{
            margin-left: 260px;
            margin-top: 35px;
            padding: 7px 15px;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
        
        /*Submit button*/
        .button_sub{
            margin-left: 240px;
            margin-top: 35px;
            padding: 7px 15px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background-color: green;
            color: white;
            text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
        }
        
        /*Reset button*/
        .button_res{
            margin-left: 60px;
            margin-top: 35px;
            padding: 7px 15px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background-color: green;
            color: white;
            text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
        }
        
        /*Text fields*/
        .textField_title{
            margin-left: 60px;
            margin-top: 30px;
            border-radius: 3px;
        }
        .textField_message{
            margin-left: 20px;
            margin-top: 30px;
            border-radius: 3px;
        }
        .textField_image{
            margin-left: 20px;
            margin-top: 30px;
            border-radius: 3px;
        }
        .textField_price{
            margin-left: 140px;
            margin-top: 60px;
            border-radius: 3px;
        }
        .textField_amount{
            margin-left: 80px;
            margin-top: 40px;
            border-radius: 3px;
        }
        /*Title - Start Date & End Date*/
        .text_Date{
            margin-left: 90px;
            color: white;
            text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
        }
        /*Date fields*/
        .Date{
            margin-left: 10px;
            margin-top: 50px;
            border-radius: 3px;
        }
```

С первым html'ем и css'ом все хорошо, все работает.

Проблема с файлами номер 2, а точнее с файлом css.
HTML отображается но css нет.

Очень странно т.к. расположение файлов одинаково.

Все это я проверяю в **Eclipse** на сервере **Tomcat 8**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Есть ли ошибки в консоли?

Comment: Нет, в кронсоле пусто.

Comment: Настоятельно рекомендую перенести теги `<title>` и `<link>` из `<body></body>` в `<head></head>`.

Comment: Спасибо, исправил!

Comment: Тег `<br />` после `<title>` тоже не нужен. Ещё странно, что у вас в CSS установлена кодировка для иврита. Проверьте имя файла `coupon.css` на наличие кириллицы. Возможно первая буква является русской "с", а не английской "c".

Comment: Решил перенести ***coupon.css*** в папку html и в самом html файле поменял к нему путь на ***href="coupon.css"***  и это тогда сработало.
То есть все дело в путь к файлу. Но что не правельно, не понимаю.

Comment: если WebContent/html/copon_html_page.html то в нем должно быть
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style/coupon.css" />
потому что папки html и css на одном уровне лежат (две точки в пути должно быть)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй указывать путь для выхода из папки html "../"

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style/company.css" />
```

Comment: Странно что первый HTML код работает с одной точкой...

Comment: Я поправил свой ответ. Когда вы пишите 2 точки "../" - вы таким образом выходите из папки. Так как ваш html находится в дочернем каталоге - нужно выйти в родительский, чтобы потом обратиться к каталогу style - "../style/company.css"

Comment: У вас этот же способ используется и в css - background-image: url('../img/backgroundLogin.gif');